# Can't align button in the nav bar

Tags: html, css

I tried creating a simple nav bar with a button on it, but seems like I can't align the button perfectly.
The Code looks like this

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #393e46;
}

.nav .logo {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: orange;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.nav .butn {
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  background: beige;
  line-height: 60px;
}

a {
  color: orange;
  font-size: x-large;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="logo">
      <ul>
        <li>Hello</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="butn">
      <a href="#">click me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I am also including the codepen link[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/kiyubi/pen/RwrYvjP)

Comment: How do you want to align the button?

Comment: @NicoShultz I want to put it in the center of the nav bar with space on the top and bottom

Answer (score 0):

Just added `margin: 10px 0` to `.nav .butn` so the remaining space is used as margin

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #393e46;
}

.nav .logo {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: orange;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.nav .butn {
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  background: beige;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

a {
  color: orange;
  font-size: x-large;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="logo">
      <ul>
        <li>Hello</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="butn">
      <a href="#">click me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks bruh, I was stuck at it for hours now. It was so simple, never thought about it

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

So here is your answer. Don't use height on every element and float property on button and logo instead use flex properties.

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .nav {
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
        background: #393e46;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .nav .logo {
        text-align: center;
        color: orange;
        font-size: xx-large;
      }

      .nav .butn {
        background: beige;
        margin: auto;
      }

      a {
        color: orange;
        font-size: x-large;
      }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
      <div class="logo">
        <ul>
          <li>Hello</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="butn">
        <a href="#">click me</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```